# Soup ui jdbc custom parameter definition

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

i use Soup ui 'JDBC Request' choice to check db result. I generally use parameter(s) as

> param = ${step name#request param}

and use it in 
`sql as select * from db where param = :param`
this is very useful for specific param. But when i try to use comma divided param, (for example 1000,10001,10003), sql query run first of it, 1000.

namely a have a request param which name as IDs and values 1000,10001,10003
i create a JDBC parameter as IDs = ${step name#IDs}
and create sql query as sql as 
`select * from db where id in (:IDs)` it only get first record of comma divided param.
As a result i wonder how to use comma divided JDBC parameter with sql select in
i get soup ui parameter from previous step request param as:
[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B58nnswDXVwmTDBsTlRLNGpwdEE)
[image]

Comment: Can you show screen shot how the value is stored?

Comment: Is id a number field? or text / varchar type?

Comment: i tried to add photo, i think my score is not enogh

Comment: yes, id is number field

Comment: i added image, i get jdbc parameter from other step' request param: jobs which a comma divided number field.

Comment: How does it shows in the `Raw` tab when you hit jdbc request?

Comment: parameter is shown as "jobs=69802%2C70154" in request raw tab

Comment: Are you also ok to use groovy script step instead of jdbc test step?

Comment: i prefer to use jdbc, the issue can be solve with groovy script request but it is difficult in jdbc request to define new values

Comment: So, assuming that you know how to solve it with groovy. Any ways, have you tried with actual values and it works instead of parameter?

Comment: yes, it works if i give value as "... in (69802,70154). but i do not want hard code, may be values changes in time.

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: @Rao i think it is impossible, so i enter values by hand which I do not want. if you say a method to solve the issue i will be satisfied. Thank you for your interest

Comment: There is an alter native way to achieve the same with the help of groovy script test step; this will set the query as needed with dynamic value, will add it as answer soon.

Comment: ok, i wait the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can send the query with multiple values `in` clause.

- Add test case level custom property, say, `IDS` and provide value as needed (separated by comma as you mentioned in the question)
- In the rest request also you can use the same as `${#TestCase#IDS}`
- In the jdbc request test step, keep query as empty. It does not matter, overrides from groovy script `query`.
- Add a groovy script test step before jdbc request test step and add the below script which would set the computed query with multiple values (dynamic as needed) `in` clause.

**Groovy Script:** follow the in-line comments.

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

//Edit the jdbc test step name if required
def nextStep = 'Compare with db results'

//Edit query if required, but not ids variable below as that is used in binding
def query = 'select * from job where id in ( $ids )'
def binding = [ids: context.testCase.getPropertyValue('IDS')]
def step = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStep]
def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(query).make(binding)

log.info "updated query : ${template.toString()}"

//Set the query to jdbc step
step.jdbcRequestTestStepConfig.query = template.toString()
```

When you run the test case, groovy script step would set the query to jdbc request.

NOTE: if jdbc test step is open, just close it and reopen to see the updated query.

Comment: thanks for answer. i do not use binding in groovy do far. i search about it a little

Comment: `binding` is variable defined which you can see below `query` statement. By the way, thanks for the question, had to look for API docs(haven't done something like that earlier) and come up with this script and I know it took a while to answer.